# MPMoviePlayerController delay when there should be virtually none

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

each time my app changes the displayed animation, which is a looping movie, he takes a pause till he finally start the movie.
The MoviePlayerConntroller is created this way

```
    self.moviePlayer = [MPMoviePlayerController alloc];
    [moviePlayer initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewChar" ofType:@"m4v"]] ];
    // remove playerview from our view (no prob is he isnt attached to any)
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    // tell our playerview the size he has to use
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 430);
    // and add hin to the superview behind everything else
    [self.view insertSubview:moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];
    // no moviecontrolls
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    // looping forever
    moviePlayer.repeatMode= MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    // let him use his own Audio Session for old devices
    moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession= NO;
    // fix the silly black background on iOS 4.3
    moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

the actual movie is played this way

```
[moviePlayer initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Whatever" ofType:@"m4v"]]];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Just as I said, each time the movie is changed, he takes a while to display it. On newer devices its ok, since they are faster, but on G2 it is somewhat disturbing.
Tried prepare playback, but that makes no difference.

Any idea what I missed?

Thanks for reading! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes time to load up the movie from disk, and obviously will be slower on older devices.  How big is the video?

Comment: 57kb. How could I hold the movie in memory? Building a stack of movieplayers for each animation would be a bit overkill. Maybe there is a better approach? The SpaceAce and DragonsLair Apps play movies. Wonder how they do that without hangs.